# Visual studio 2013 Asp.net Configuration tool

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I need help with starting Asp.net configuration tool in Visual studio 2013.

I found some sample here:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx

And I tried to implement it in my environment, but unsuccessful.
This is my app solution path: 
F:\DropBox\Code\MvcMusicStore\MvcMusicStore\MvcMusicStore.csproj 
This is my framework path:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles

So, I create this path:
iisexpress.exe /path:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:”/ASP.NETWebAdminFiles” /port:8082 /clr:4.0 /ntlm”

but it doesn't work. Can someone help me with creating correct cmd path ?

I am getting cmd error "The following switch is invalid: '/ntlm'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I successed to open configuration by creating dummy website project in VS 2012 and use it's url to configuring asp.net  users/roles ..only I had change path to my VS 2013 project..

```
http://localhost:23580/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=F:\DropBox\Code\MvcMusicStore\MvcMusicStore\&applicationUrl=/
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad to see that you solved your issue.

But creating a dummy project in vs2012 is not a neccessary step. I answered a question about that issue just now and wanted to share that with you also.

[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool/20555928#20555928)

Have a look at this answer.

P.S. I would write that as a comment if I had enough reputation, that's why I am sending that as an answer. Sorry about that in advance :)