# Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and as you probably know there is no ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool. I wanted as always make fast roles etc. I tried enable it using this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments . But I'm getting "Invalid application path" error. Any solutions to this error or workarounds?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

On the console, copy and paste exactly what is written here:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

It doesn't matter if you open cmd.exe with administrator privileges or not, just copy paste the above code on the console and don't exit with "q" until you're done!

Then open a browser window and write this on the address bar:

```
http://localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=[Exact_Project_Path]\&applicationUrl=/
```

Be sure to copy & paste your project path from windows explorer as it is, it will work ;)

I hope Microsoft adds this back to the next update of VS2013! It's not convenient for anybody to copy & paste codes around just to handle membership like we did in the past...

**IMPORTANT EDIT: I am sorry, I just realized that it matters if you start the console with administrator privileges. Don't do that. If console has administrator rights, the Web Configuration Tool shows this error on the Security page:**

> *There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient
> permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not
> being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where
> you can choose a new data store.  The following message may help in
> diagnosing the problem: Access to the path
> 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
> Files\root\1c3fef5c\2180c7f9\hash' is denied.*

Comment: It helped the problem was I was trying to do this in program files (x86) not program files... My mistake. Thanks for help.

Comment: @capcode01 If it asks for a username and password, it's your User account and password for your PC

Comment: @chrisamanse and what if you dont have a username and password on your PC?

Comment: Then I strongly recommend that you create a password for your username immediately. That is the first thing a user should do after buying a new computer or installing new O.S. ;)

Comment: do not paste 2nd line directly into addressbar.
change [Exact_Project_Path] to your project directory which has webconfig file. something c:\mywebApp1
(Im assuming myWebApp1 directory has an webconfig file.)
if you do it. it wont ask any username or password.

Comment: Be careful tho 
`"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm` 
runs IIS as 64 bit. If you want to run the IIS Express as 32 bit, you have to use 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm`
 (IIS 8 and up). Hope that helps you from a headache :)

Comment: @ilter - 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: @nerdspal, I think you're forgetting the double quotes. When working with command line, if your path has any spaces, you should surround the path with double quotes to help command promt to parse the path correctly.

Comment: A point of confusion: When it says, "don't exit with "q" until you're done!", does that mean to leave the command prompt open while I punch in the URL?

Comment: I keep entering the command line. The paths are valid, but my returned value is: `Copied template config file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\AppServer\applicationhost.config' to 'C:\Users\jp2code\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\applicationhost20158253210335.config' 

Invalid application path`

Comment: @jp2code, yes you're right. You can access the site as long as the commandline is working. Once you close cmd screen, it's done. About the error you're getting, there may be a lot of reasons for it but mainly the user you're logged in to your comp don't have the previledges to complete the job. See if your user is in the administrators group, for starters.

Comment: what to do when the page times out? I restarted IIS from command prompt but it still say the page has time out

Comment: @ilter the page works but if you don't do anything on the page lets say for 10 min, the page times out. The problem is how to bring it back?

Comment: I believe that is not related to the question above. Please open a new thread about that issue, since the timed out page is also a .net web page which has its own config.

Answer (score 7):

If you're being asked for username and password, do this:

1. Open up Firefox and type in about:config as the url
2. In the Filter Type in "ntlm"
3. Double click "network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris" and type in "localhost" and hit enter

source: http://forums.codecharge.com/posts.php?post_id=81959

Comment: I tried this. It still asks for username and password.

Comment: provide your windows login credentials

Answer (score 0):

This did work for me till creating a security role and then a user but then when I try to run my website  get the following message 
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
Most likely causes:
•A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
•If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
• Enable directory browsing. 1.Go to the IIS Express install directory.
2.Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
3.Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.

•Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Comment: Moving to Identity framework may or may not be an option to me. I am interested in knowing why it doesnt work for me after applying all steps.   Even if i use appcmd command to enable directory browsing i still keep on getting the above error. Clueless at the moment on how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source utility named "Credentials Manager for WCF" which I downloaded from [here](http://www.idesign.net/Downloads/GetDownload/1909). It needs below configurations to work. 

For configurations, you should edit configuration file of project "CredentialServiceHost" as follows:

```
    *<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <clear />
        <add name="AspNetDbConnectionString" connectionString="[Your data base connection string]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="[Your data base connection string]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>


  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None"/>
  <roleManager enabled="true"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="AspNetSqlProviderService" behaviorConfiguration="MEX Enabled">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IApplicationManager"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IMembershipManager"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IPasswordManager"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IRoleManager"/>
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IUserManager"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="TransactionalWS" transactionFlow="true">
                    <reliableSession enabled="True"/>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MEX Enabled">
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

and for project "CredentialsManager" you should use following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
         <section name="CredentialsManagerClient.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
      </sectionGroup>
   </configSections>
   <applicationSettings>
      <CredentialsManagerClient.Properties.Settings>
         <setting name="AspNetSqlProviderService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://localhost:8000</value>
         </setting>
      </CredentialsManagerClient.Properties.Settings>
   </applicationSettings>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <client>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IApplicationManager"/>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IMembershipManager"/>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IPasswordManager"/>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IRoleManager"/>
         <endpoint address="http://localhost:8000/" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactionalWS" contract="IUserManager"/>
      </client>
      <bindings>
         <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="TransactionalWS" transactionFlow="true">
               <reliableSession enabled="True"/>
            </binding>
         </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
   </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Run the "CredentialsServiceHost.exe" file as an administrator then run the "CredentialsManager.exe" file.