# How to implement role based authorization in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I'm working on a school project and I need to implement Role-based authorization in an ASP.NET mvc3 application. Currently the application only stores the user's role in a field in the database and there is only one login page. I need to alter the entire application in other for it to grant different content to different users including admin, supervisor and counselors (counselors are able to input new client info and edit and view client information that they inputted. Supervisors can view and edit all client info and also view and edit counselor info. Admin has crud access to everything on the application.)

I'm not sure about what other info to provide about the application but i'll really appreciate any help i can get as i am new to ASP.net mvc as a whole. Most of the tutorials i found focus on specific piece of the role based approach. I need more of a bottom-up approach to implementing the roles and its authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ASPNET configuration tool. I believe that it's what you're looking for:

[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool/20555928#20555928)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy40ytx0.aspx