# Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 and Memberships

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

As you know, Microsoft removed ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool in VS2013 and it is a bad downgrade for it. thanks [**THIS**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool) post that shows a way (but difficult) to use ASP.NET Configuration Tool.
so what is the **easiest** way to define memberships, roles, users, access rules and ...?
ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool was really simple and user friendly.

Any more suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft is moving membership system from Membership Provider to [ASP.NET Identity](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity).

However, if you want to use Membership Provider there is a new one called [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

ASP.NET Universal Providers supports NuGet package, and the package will create the requires membership tags in web.config.

[image]

Comment: it's good for create membership provider in web.config
but ASP web configuration tool was a great tool to create users, roles, define access roles for folders, it creates web.config in folders and was very easy to use.
I don't know why microsoft removed it.
How do you create users and roles now? probably you write some codes and create a page like ASP configuration tool

Comment: I find aspnetmemberman.codeplex.com.
it is almost what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up membership/roles isn't much difficult once you understand the basics. You will love to set things up directly in the web.config, once you start using it.

Check these:

[Setting up Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx)

[Setting up authorization rules](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)