# How can I launch the ASP.net configuration website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I'm trying to create a membership system and I have been looking at this link:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7 
In the step that says 'Adding an Administrative User with the ASP.NET Configuration site' I don't have that on VS. Mine is VS 2013 Update4. Or is there any way I can enable roles? Also, any link that teaches membership and authorization for asp.net is welcome. Any suggestions would be highly appreaciated. Thank you!

Comment: That was removed from VS I think in VS 2012 when the new identity features were added, which has been replacing the traditional ASP.Net membership providers.

Comment: Refer [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool)