# ASP.NET Configuration for Configuration Membership

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, configuration, asp.net-membership

I'm working with ASP.Net Application and i have followed this Walkthrough https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/879kf95c.aspx but i'm having a problem with Configuration Membership Section ! i'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 but i can't find ASP.NET Configuration anywhere !

could anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net Configuration is no longer part of Visual Studio (since VS2013). You can still access it though, by manually starting IIS Express as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx).
See also [Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool).