# Unable to access temporary asp.net files

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express

I'm running Win 10, VS Express for Web 2015.  I have an existing asp.net membership database that I want to amend using the Web Site Administration Tool.

I followed this hack to manually start the Web Site Administration Tool via the IIS: [Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool)

The Web Site Administration Tool launches fine.  However, when I go to the security tab, I get the following error message: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\19aec8c6\ee1f4195\hash' is denied.

I've gone into the Temporary ASP.Net files folder and changed the properties for my userid to give me full control, yet I continue to run up against the same error.

Update: I turned on the IIS in the Windows Feature and that seemed to make some progress.  Now when I run the Web Site Administration Tool, I get a different error when I click on the security tab: Access to the path 'C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\19aec8c6\ee1f4195\hash' is denied.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running your applications in with administrator privileges? Has the IIS user full control as well?

Comment: Tried giving I is full user control of the temporary internet files folder in the Windows directory. Didn't make any difference. Got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you notice the update left on [the referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20555928/6722);

> **IMPORTANT EDIT: I am sorry, I just realized that it matters if you start console with administrator priviledges. Don't do that. If console has administrator rights, the Web Configuration Tool shows this error on the Security page:**
>
> There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Access to the path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1c3fef5c\2180c7f9\hash' is denied.

Looks like the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did see the update and I don't open the command prompt with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change **TEMP** location to  "**C:\Windows\Temp**" and restart Visual Studio

If you wish, you can reset TEMP location to "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp" after work fine.

[image: Nilesh Umaretiya]