# Web Admin Tool - Users registered in website are stored in different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm exploring Website Administration Tool. Since this tool is unavailable in Visual Studio 2012, I'm using [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool) to create roles, members and restrict access. I have a sample website `Test` which is a Web Forms Site with a default login, register and home pages.

My problem is this:

When I add a user using the Web Admin tool, I can't log in with that user in the `Test` website. The data is however stored in the appropriate database.

If I register in the `Test` website, I can log in. But this is not reflected in my `aspnet_Membership, asp_Users, etc` tables in the database. Instead, I find out that new tables have appeared. Namely: `AspnetUsers, AspnetRoles, etc.` This is where my user, who registered in the website, is stored.

So the user added through website is stored in a different table than the ones added through the Web Admin Tool. That's why I can't log in using the users added through Web Admin Tool.

Is there any way I can *force* the Login and Registered pages not to create new tables in my database? And instead, use the data from the 'aspnet_Membership, asp_Users, etc.' when users are logging in? I want to be able to log in using the users I added in WAT, and be able to see the registered users in WAT too.

Any help would be appreciated!